# Unable to install ngx-slick-carousel

Tags: angular

I am trying to install `slick-carousel` in my angular project. I have been following the steps from here :- https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-slick-carousel. These two steps are working :-

```
 npm install jquery --save
 npm install slick-carousel --save
```

while doing the following command

```
npm install ngx-slick-carousel --save
```

i am getting the following error

[image: console image]

Comment: So did you try npm install ngx-slick-carousel --save --force like it says? Also take a look at their github https://github.com/leo6104/ngx-slick-carousel/issues their library doesn't support ng10+

Comment: Also alternatively https://github.com/mehmet-erim/ngx-slickjs#readme

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There two ways to try in your case. It is probably because of upstream dependency conflict. Try doing as follows...

npm install --legacy-peer-deps --save ngx-slick-carousel

Next way is to use --force flag to install the package.

Comment: Thank you! npm install --legacy-peer-deps --save ngx-slick-carousel worked

Answer (score 0):

try remove node_module folder and .lock file and run npm install after npm install ngx-slick-carousel --save